# my rest call is triggering twice, i am using angularjs

Tags: jquery, angularjs, web-services

my rest call is triggering twice when i call it from ui.. i am using java v8 and angularjs v1.6 here is the service

```
import com.project123.temp.component.ImportFileComponent;

@Component
@Path("project123/ImportFileService")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)

public class ImportFileService {

    @Autowired
    private ImportFileComponent ImportFileComponent;


    @Path("/invoiceImportService")
    @POST
    @Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
    @Transactional
    public Response validateImportFile(File filename){
                ImportFileComponent.validateImportFile(filename);
        return null; 

    }
}
```

here is my controller function inangularJS

```
$("#importInvoice").on('change', prepareUpload);
    function prepareUpload(event){
        files = event.target.files;
        console.log(files[0]);
        $http({
            method : 'POST',
            url : 'project123/ImportFileService/invoiceImportService',
            data : files[0] 
        }).then(function success(response){
            console.log(response);
        }, function error(response){
            console.log(response);
        });
    }
```

Can any one help understanding me why?  If you require further data, I can provide it.

Comment: I don't know the rest of your code, but using an event such as  `$("#importInvoice").on('change')` seems to be a weird way to call your API... I have the feeling this event is called twice, recovering two times your data.

Comment: My initial gut reaction is the `.on('change', prepareUpload)` needs to be more specific. Something like `.on('click', prepareUpload)`. That's really just a guess though. How do you know it's firing twice? Does your brower track 2 requests being sent or are you catching that in the controller server side?

Comment: @TheDude yeah im monitering it from browser with console.log... the call is triggering twice.. also only after 2nd call only 1st call response is responding

Comment: The whole `files[0]` thing is a bit weird too. Why not just get the file rather than an array of files? It makes me curious to know the html around `#importInvoice`

Comment: @Mistalis thanks for ur respose ill try to chnge that in alternate...

Comment: I'd eliminate the use of Jquery and make use of Angular to actually call your function when the appropriate event takes place. Without seeing your HTML, I'd assume you'd want to call this via ng-click on an upload button.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#importInvoice").on('change', prepareUpload);
```

instead of this block of code... i replaced with

```
$("#importInvoice").off('change').on('change', prepareUpload);
```

now its working absolutely fine... no other changes have done. it is jquery itseems.